# Can standard JS libraries be used in Vue.js/React?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, vue.js

Without Vue/React I "developed" applications in Vanilla Javascript. There I used some libraries to reuse code from others. Take [chart.js](https://www.chartjs.org/) as an example: I used it to plot a chart in an [election application](https://github.com/DyeffersonAz/mostrador-eleicao).

*Bootstrap*, for example, has a package that is specific to [Vue](https://bootstrap-vue.org/) or [React](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/). What are the benefits of an specific "library" to the framework?

## Applications that don't have specific packages

Now, let's see [chart.js](https://www.chartjs.org/): out of my research I haven't found a specific package to Vue.js. How can I use it if so? What about CSS wrappers like [Primer](https://primer.style/css/) and [Fomantic-ui](https://fomantic-ui.com/)? Can I do the same thing as in static applications?

Sorry if this is confuse somehow. If necessary, please ask me for clarification in the comments.

Comment: Your question makes sense, I think. React in particular is very opinionated and works nothing like vanilla JS. Many popular libraries have wrappers, but some don't. It is usually possible (and for the most part not too difficult) to wrap them yourself by hooking them up to React's lifecycle methods. IDK about vue. Anything more specific than that will depend on the library in question.

Comment: @JaredSmith Wrapping them myself? Can you please detail this a little bit more? Are there any links on that?

Comment: I cannot, at least not in the space of a comment, and probably not in the space of an answer either it will depend on what you're wrapping. Nor is there any set pattern for doing so, but you may want to check out some stuff like [this, the React wrapper for the popular leaflet.js library](https://github.com/PaulLeCam/react-leaflet). Basically you turn the classes of the thing you're wrapping into React components.

Comment: The Vue wrapper for Chart.js is [`vue-chartjs`](https://vue-chartjs.org/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think any UI library is mostly concerned with the framework specific way of handling things like view updates, rendering, and styling. The frameworks have different concepts regarding those things and therefore individual libs are often necessary to utilize a frameworks ability. When something is being rendered differences in the frameworks have to be taken into account. Therefore you often see library versions for each FE-framework

On the other side, Javascript will always work and therefore a library which bundles functionality (e.g. moment, lodash) can be used in every framework in usually the same way.

If you want to share UI components I strongly recommend using web components which solve framework specific problems like styling as a web standard. You can use them with every framework (e.g Ionic).

In conclusion: JS libraries which aren't concerned with rendering can usually be reused. When it comes to UI libraries, like bootstrap as you mentioned, components often have to be written for each framework. Web components can be a solution because they work with every framework as well as vanilla JS.

Comment: So the packages/libraries won't work if not framework specific?

Comment: No, UI libraries like bootstrap usually wont work, except you are utilizing web components. Any common JS library (e.g. moment.js, lodash) will work anyway because it is just Javascript not concerned with implementation details of the framework on how to create the appropriate HTML & CSS.

Comment: Edit your answer to emphasize this comment. This is the best one.

Comment: I have edited the answer and extended them with examples. Sorry for my grammar as it was very late when I answered your question originally.